# Why withLatestFrom don't return latest value?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I use some `BehaviourRelay` for some variable. And I use `withLatestFrom` for one of them. But `withLatestFrom` didn't return the latest value I bind to it.

If I use `combineLatest`. It works but I want to know why the code with `withLatestFrom` not work

```
let dueDate = BehaviorRelay<Date?>(value: nil)
let numberScheduleDays = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 1)
let selectedPaymentDate = BehaviorRelay<Date?>(value: nil)

dueDate.asObservable()
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMap { Observable.from(optional: $0) }
    .map { self.addDaysForDate(days: 1, date: $0) }
    .bind(to: selectedPaymentDate)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

selectedPaymentDate.asObservable()
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .withLatestFrom(dueDate.asObservable()) { (selectedDate: $0, dueDate: $1) }
    .map { self.daysBetweenDates(startDate: $0.dueDate, endDate: $0.selectedDate) }
    .bind(to: numberScheduleDays)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

dueDate.accept(Date())
```

After block one `selectedPaymentDate.value = Date() + 1`
But in block two `dueDate` still emit `nil` value. I wonder why its value is not `Date()`

Answer (score 1):

`withLatestFrom` assumes that two observable sequence have different source and they don't fire simultaneously (Like in your case they have same source).

If two observable sequences fire simultaneously then they can be solved by using single sequence.

For more info read:

[withLatestFrom doesn't actually provide latest value](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1121)